# Reference is changing after object is serialized?

Tags: java, android, serialization

So here I have this code in my `Fragment`:

```
ProductParams params = (ProductParams) getArguments().getSerializable("product_params");
Log.i("TAG", "setupFragment: "+params.getChampionId());
params.setChampionId(100);
params = (ProductParams) getArguments().getSerializable("product_params");
Log.i("TAG", "setupFragment: "+params.getChampionId());
```

`params.getChampionId()` for the first log is 0. But surprisingly the value for the second log is 100 while I expect it to be 0 (the initial value). Why is it so? And how can I have the `getArguments().getSerializable("product_params")` return the intial value?

Comment: The second `Log` returns the initial data that you sent as the argument. i.e, Both `Log` are identical. Please specify what do you want to do...

Comment: @Vishnu My question was confusing. I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: You set the value to `100` in `params.setChampionId(100);`  !

Comment: Okay. But then again I reference `params` to serialized object from arguments. Does it mean that when I change a filed of `params` object, in fact I am changing the serialized object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bundle class *caches* deserialized objects, which means `getSerializable` will return a reference to the same object every time. If you change a field in that object, you will see that change through every reference.

For this reason, it's not a good idea to pass mutable objects as parameters in bundles, or otherwise. You wouldn't have this problem if there was no `ProductParams.setChampionId`.

Comment: That was the point I didn't know. Thanks. So Android's standard way of passing data to `Fragment` is by using `Bundle`. What other method could be more convenient? @Joni

Comment: Depends on the case. The arguments bundle is convenient for data that the fragment does not modify because it's persisted through activity life cycle events